# How to get rest of paragraph to animate on More... link?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, expand

Basically, I can not get the More... link to animate the height of the next span when the link that has a class `"dropdown"` is clicked on. It just doesn't animate at all.  It animates only when it is changed to a `Less...` link and the `Less...` link gets clicked to collapse the extra content in the paragraph.  How can I get the `More...` link to animate when the content becomes shown?  I am currently toggling the height, should I be doing something else instead?

Using the following jQuery code in `$(document).ready(function() { });`

```
$(".listitem").on("click", ".dropdown", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var type = $this.next("span").length > 0 && !$this.next("span").is(":visible") ? 'expand' : 'collapse';
    var theSpan = type == 'expand' ? $this.next("span") : $this.prev("span");
    if (type == 'expand') {
        $this.insertAfter(theSpan);
    }
    else
        $this.insertBefore(theSpan);

    theSpan.animate({height: 'toggle'}, 250, function(){
        $this.text(type == 'expand' ? ' [ Less... ]' : '[ More... ]');
    });
});
```

I have the following structured HTML within a `ul` tag (All `li` tags are the same structure):

```
<li>
   <div class="listitem">
      <span style="font-weight: bold;">Headline</span> Here is some body copy for the headline that should expand with an animation when clicking on the More... link right here. <a href="#" class="dropdown red">[ More... ]</a><span class="hidden">Here is more text to be shown and it should animate when the More... link is clicked, but it currently does not!</span>
   </div>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
ul
{
    list-style: none outside none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul li
{
    padding: .4em;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.listitem
{
    display: table;
}
.hidden
{
    display: none;
}
```

**EDIT**

You can see the problem here:  http://opportunityfinance.net/Test/conference-2013/highlights.html

I need the text to stay on the same line when it is expanded, it should not be pushed to the next line down.  Is there some sort of `white-space` css way of doing this?  or perhaps `display: inline`??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jDeuH/1/ This is what I got from your posted code. When More... is clicked the content is being shown. What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to get it to animate the way it does when `Less...` is clicked.  I need it to animate (slide down) the way it slides up when `Less...` is clicked.  But should slide down instead when `More...` is clicked.

Comment: Actually, I am using a class, called: `.hidden { display: none; }` on the span, and not using `style="display: none;"`... Updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only thing I can think of then. Just shows / hides each letter one at a time.

It will only become html once the text is fully loaded.

```
$(".expander").each(function(e) {
    var expanded = false, 
        isExpanding = false, 
        $this = $(this).text("[More...]");
    $this.click(function() {
        if(!isExpanding) {            
            isExpanding = true;
            if(!expanded) {
                var i = 0, 
                    interval = setInterval(function() {
                    if(i < $this.prev().text().length) {
                        $this.prev().prev().text($this.prev().text().substring(0, i));
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        $this.prev().prev().html($this.prev().html());
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        isExpanding = false;
                    }
               }, 1000 / 60);                
            } else {
                var i = $this.prev().text().length - 1, 
                    interval = setInterval(function() {
                    if(i >= 0) {
                        $this.prev().prev().text($this.prev().text().substring(0, i));
                        i--;
                    } else {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        isExpanding = false;
                    }
                }, 1000 / 60);

            }
            expanded = !expanded;
        }
    });
}).prev().before("<span></span>").hide();
```

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/CxX8n/9/

Comment: Ok, so you are using `div` tags and that only causes the text to be pushed onto the next line when expanding it (clicking on the `More...` link), so this is no good.  I need to expand it within a `span` or within some element that is going to STAY EXACTLY where it is in the paragraph.  It can't go to the next line when expanded.  It needs to replace the `More...` which should be `inline` with the paragraph, with the rest of the copy.

Comment: Added link of where you can see this problem occurring.

Comment: Now that is very very interesting....  Thanks, going to try and implement it now...  If works, than you the man!!!

Comment: Where do I put the text to change `[ More... ]` to `[ Less... ]`?

Comment: Hold, on, but this removes all links from within the text that gets shown.  How do I get back the links???

Comment: Ok, so I just changed to `.html()`, instead of `.text()`, but now it seems really really choppy...  For example, there is tons of lag in it.  You can see here:  http://opportunityfinance.net/Test/conference-2013/highlights.html It really happens when it drops to the very next line.

Comment: yeah i caught that as well. it may because i did not provide the second argument to setinterval function. EDIT MADE

Comment: Ok I made the last edit...My assumption is a dom issue. So the supplied code will use text until the last load which uses html. If this does not make you happy then I concede

Comment: YOU NAILED IT BRO!  Thanks sooooo MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

`<span>` is an inline element so the height property doesn't apply.  But you are trying to toggle height which is why `animate()` keeps forcing `display: inline-block`, and why it doesn't work the first time.  So instead, try toggling `opacity`.

```
$(".listitem").on("click", ".dropdown", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var type = $this.next("span").length > 0 && !$this.next("span").is(":visible") ? 'expand' : 'collapse';
    var theSpan = type == 'expand' ? $this.next("span") : $this.prev("span");
    if (type == 'expand') {
        $this.insertAfter(theSpan);
    }
    else
        $this.insertBefore(theSpan);

    theSpan.animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, 250, function(){
        $this.text(type == 'expand' ? ' [ Less... ]' : '[ More... ]');
    });
});
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eKWV9/)

Comment: This is no good, because it adds `display: inline-block` to the span.  Don't ask me how, but this is what happens in Chrome and causes the span to drop to a new line, instead of staying where it is in the paragraph.

Comment: This is using your code:  http://opportunityfinance.net/Test/conference-2013/highlights.html

Comment: @SolomonClosson Updated my answer for you.

Comment: It's your approach, just with one word changed :)

Comment: haha, yeah, changed `height` to `opacity`... nice, didn't think of that! ;)